# getInvokedFunctionArn Deprecated?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Was wondering if context.getInvokedFunctionArn() got deprecated? I googled it and nothing came up about deprecation.

My problem is I cannot call this method.
[image]

When I go inside the Context class:

[image]

But it seems to be there on the AWS github ... ? https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/Context.java
A bit confused about this.

If this method is truly not available, how would I get invoked function arn name?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Okay nevermind I fixed it. Absent-minded mistake. getInvokedFunctionArn is available in aws-lambda-java-core 1.1.0 but not 1.0.0.